# Separation of Noble Metals for scrap recovery

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, noble-metals

I am researching scrap metal recovery as a side job and am hitting a wall with the noble metals. Gold, Silver, Platinum, and Palladium seem like they're all fairly easy to recover. I just can't find a process to separate the rest (Re, Ru, Os, Ir, Rh), not even a description of the industrial processes.

I suppose what I'm looking for is a full reactivity series for these metals, and any lead on a separation process.

Eventually I'd like to expand this to all transition metals (Scandium is more valuable than Platinum from what I've read) and the Lanthanides. So any info down that rabbit hole would be appreciated too.

I appreciate the time of whoever answers here. I can get my business off the ground with the knowledge I already have, but adding that extra recovery of trace noble metals would add an element (pun intended) of fun as well. I'd hate to see all that dust go to waste.

Comment: Where would you get scrap that contains e.g. Os?

Comment: As it stands, the question looks quite vague and broad (this doesn't mean it's useless). Probably you could add more details as to what kind of scrap you are dealing with. Obsolete consumer electronics, foundry waste a fallen Soyuz rocket are quite different beasts.

Comment: Good point. Mainly jewelry, electronics parts, catalytic converters, & spark plugs.